# Generated Application Controller #needs does not include itself

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-cli, controllers

I'm migrating a web app from ember tools to ember-cli and having issues.  So far I've been able to handle all of the errors, but not this one.  I have an `auth` controller.  On several pages I include the `needs:["auth"]`, but the error that I'm seeing when restarting my server is quite odd.

```
ReferenceError: (generated application controller)#needs does not 
include `auth`. To access the auth controller from (generated application
controller), (generated application controller) should have a `needs` 
property that is an array of the controllers it has access to.
```

I'm not sure what the error means necessarily, I'm able to debug the compiled script in Firebug, but it's not working when I try adding any `needs:whatever` to the auth controller itself.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In your application template, do you have something like {{controllers.auth....}}?

Comment: @Kingpin2k - thank you, this led to the answer.  My partner did not originally copy the application controller over from our ember tools app.  It's fixed now.  Thank you so much!